# What is the significance of this circuit?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, i2c, gas-sensor

It is a part of a sensor circuit on I2C lines. But why are MOSFETs being used to connect pull up resistors for I2C lines?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this [application note](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf) which explains how this circuit acts as a bi-direction level shifter.

Comment: Level shifter. https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/logic-level-shifting-basics

Comment: @ga-alpha - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.).

Comment: (continued)  I *guess* you copied that partial schematic from [this PDF](https://dfimg.dfrobot.com/nobody/wiki/70e5ccaae18896bcb61afc863a1e1259.pdf) linked from [this page](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/SKU_SEN0514_Gravity_ENS160_Air_Quality_Sensor). || Please [edit] your question to add a link to the source that you actually used, and remember to add the required references for copied/adapted content in future. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson got it. will take care of that in future. I will also read the rules. Also how did you got to know which sensor is it from the above screenshot?